# return std::map with a getter method

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, stdmap

As the title indicates I'm trying to grab on to a std::map container and return it.

I get the following error: invalid use of template-name 'std::map' without an argument list

Now I pretty sure the reason has to do with templates, but simply haven't found an example that describes my specific situation.

My program i rather simple since I'm a newbie on parantal leave. It consists of these files:

- main.cpp
- Movie_Archive.hpp
- Movie_Archive.cpp
- Movie.hpp
- Movie.cpp
- Helper.hpp
- Helper.cpp

I don't think anyone wants me to paste all the code so I've pasted the parts that I belive to be vital to my question. Code below:

Movie_Archive.hpp

```
class MovieArchive {
private:
std::map <std::string, Movie> movie_archive;

public:
std::map getMovieArchive();
};
```

Movie_Archive.cpp

```
std::map MovieArchive::getMovieArchive() {
    return movie_archive;
}
```

main.cpp

```
TheMovieArchive.controlArchiveStatus(TheMovieArchive.getMovieArchive(), TheMovieArchive.getTitle());
```

// Checks if the movie title already has been entered

Thank soo much for taking a look. I hope someone can find a solution.

Kind regards//Alle

Comment: Just like you have `std::map <std::string, Movie>` when you declare `movie_archive` you have to use the same thing as the return type, or just use `auto`

Comment: map is a template - you want `std::map <std::string,Movie> getMovieArchive();` and similar elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean

```
class MovieArchive {
private:
  std::map <std::string, Movie> movie_archive;

public:
  std::map<std::string, Movie> getMovieArchive();
};
```

i.e., you have to provide the template parameters in the return type of the getter as well.

BTW: you probably want to write

```
class MovieArchive {
private:
  std::map <std::string, Movie> movie_archive;

public:
  const std::map<std::string, Movie> & getMovieArchive();
};
```

i.e. returning a const reference instead of a copy of the internal data structure.

Comment: You might also consider using a `typedef`/`using` statement to simplify the declarations, eg: `typedef std::map<std::string, Movie> MovieMap;` or `using MovieMap = std::map<std::string, Movie>;`, and then you can do this: `MovieMap movie_archive; ... const MovieMap& getMovieArchive()`. Or, just use `auto` instead: `const auto& getMovieArchive() { return movie_archive; }`  Either way, you should also consider declaring `getMovieArchive()` itself as `const` as well